# Detect data pattern generated with a specific frequency

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, signal-processing

Let's assume I have several signal generators, each signal generator has a specific frequency. For example, Generator A generates number +3 every 3 seconds, Generator B generates number +4 every 5 seconds, etc.

I don't know how many signal generators there are, neither do I know their frequency or generated numbers. But I do have a stream of timestamps and numbers of all these generators produce. Of course the timestamps may be off by a bit, for example I might see Generator A generates +3 at 0.5, 3.51, 6.49, etc. The signals might also be off -- I might see +2.99, +3.01. We can assume they are not off by a lot. Not all numbers in the stream are generated by a fixed-frequency signal generator.

Are there any existing algorithms I can use, to find out the generators behind the stream? I don't expect to find all the generators, but I would like to have as many as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factorial hidden markov model would probably work for this task (http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~sfchang/course/spr/papers/factorial-HMM-97.pdf). There is also the infinite factorial hidden markov model (http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00004287/01/nips08.pdf), which might be able to adaptively detect the number of generators in your system. Unfortunately, I don't know of any available implementations of these models.

You could also try Independent Component Analysis on fixed length windows of your data (googling should find a number of implementations).